# encoding xlsx as base64 and send it as an attachment

Tags: java

I have an assignment where i need to create a .xlsx and convert it to base64 and this file will sent as an attachment in an email webservice.The code for conversion of .xlsx to base64 is as below:

```
import java.io.*;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

public class Test {
  public static void main(String [] args) {

     String fileName = "C:/Users/kk.txt";

    try {
          byte[] buffer = new byte[1000];

        FileInputStream inputStream = 
            new FileInputStream(fileName);

        int total = 0;
        int nRead = 0;
        String reference=null;
        while((nRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                           String name=(new String(buffer));
            byte[] encodedBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(name.getBytes());

            System.out.println(new String(encodedBytes));

        }   

      inputStream.close();      

      System.out.println("Read " + total + " bytes"); 
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println(
            "Unable to open file '" + 
            fileName + "'");                
    }
    catch(IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(
            "Error reading file '" 
            + fileName + "'");                  
        // Or we could just do this: 
        // ex.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

but when i send it as a mail using BPEL and when i open the file it shows general input/output error.But when i send it as a text it works fine. Should i not use this code for excel or where am i wrong.Am totally new to java.

Comment: Can you clarify "when i send it as a text it works fine"?  Do you mean that when you send the file as base64 encoded text in an email attachment via a program other than BPEL that it works?

Comment: no when i convert a .txt file using the code above and send it as an attachment using BPEL i am able to view the attachment but it shows error when i view .xlsx file.

Answer (score 3):

Okay - my guess is that you're not changing the mimetype etc features of the email you're creating for the attachment ( and that it's default is text/html ).

Take a look [here](http://ariklalo.com/2013/01/21/adding-a-file-as-an-attachment-to-an-email-activity-on-bpel-10g/) - which is for a word doc instead - but outlines what I think you should be doing ( assuming I found the right kind of BPEL )

For your file type ".xlsx", [this table](http://filext.com/faq/office_mime_types.php) shows the appropriate mime-type is like

```
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
```

Comment: I am using the MIME type you ve suggested but still this issue persists.I get a pop up showing general input/output error.The main question in my mind is there a a totally differnet way to convert xls files to base64?shouldnt i use the code i used above?

Comment: The base64 encoding you're doing looks alright to me, but you could test it w/o the email by making a base64 decoder and then re-reading the output back into excel.  I would expect the content-transfer-encoding to be set to base64 in the email.  You could view the email source of the received email in both cases to see if that's the case.  You could also check out what another email client does when attaching an .xlxs file by viewing the resulting message source it produces and comparing it to your case that's not working.  If I get a chance, I'll try your code on an .xlxs file later.

Answer (score 2):

```
package com.denemeler;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Base64;

public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String filePath = "D:\\test.xls";
        File file = new File(filePath);
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) file.length()];
        fis.read(bytes);
        String base64 = new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode(bytes);

        String destinationPath = "D:\\Destination\\donusmusHali.xls";

        //decode Base64 String to image
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(destinationPath); 
        bytes = new sun.misc.BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(base64);
        fos.write(bytes);


        fis.close();
        fos.close();
    }

}
```

this code works for encoding and decoding excel files.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, we use filename.xls in outputStream to write our excel workbook.
But if need to send it over network in base64 format then ByteArrayOutputStream is the option to go for it:

```
Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
ByteArrayOutputStream b = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
try {
    workbook.write(b);
}catch(FileNotFoundException e){
  e.printStackTrace();
}catch(Exception e){
  e.printStackTrace();
}
byte[] bytes = bos.toByteArray(
);
Base64.encodeBase64String(bytes);
```

This solution worked for me, As first excel was created using Apache POI then applied above code and converted it to base64, which when decoded over network then encoded file was getting opened in a excel application as expected. :)

You can follow same on https://nupur28ag.blogspot.com/2020/01/get-base64-from-excel-created-using.html